# SQL Server : Histogram of the starts and stops over time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get a histogram of the of the starts and stops over time from a subscriber DB, I know what the result should be but I can't make it work.

The code I am trying is:

[image]

Unfortunately I get the message

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

If I try

[image]

It doesn`t work either:

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 2
>   The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

How can I get over this and get a histogram table?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the data type of `start_date`, `stop_date` ?

Comment: You should post the **code as text** - not a screenshot thereof

Comment: Hi, it is a varchar(50) . The stop_date contain some values that are "NULL"

Comment: I just thought the screenshot would look better to understand

Comment: Then filter the `NULL` values by `WHERE stop_date IS NOT NULL`

Comment: Not sure how to do this Arulkumar:

Comment: You mean change this line ? YEAR(CONVERT(Datetime,stop_date,104))

Comment: No. next to from: `FROM Subscribers WHERE stop_date IS NOT NULL`

Comment: How the stop_date is stored in your table. Because `DECLARE @End_date AS VARCHAR(50) = '2016-05-15'; SELECT YEAR (CONVERT(DATETIME, @End_date, 104));` this is failes

Comment: USE Subscribers
SELECT theyear, SUM(isstart) as starts, SUM(isstop) as stops
FROM ((SELECT YEAR(CONVERT(Datetime,start_date,104)) as theyear, 1 as isstart, 0 as isstop
FROM Subscribers s)
UNION ALL
(SELECT YEAR(CONVERT(Datetime,stop_date,104)), 0 as isstart, 1 as isstop
FROM Subscribers s WHERE stop_date IS NOT NULL)
)s
GROUP BY theyear
ORDER BY theyear

Comment: I am afraid I don't get it right

Comment: Could you please check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your comments, the start_date and stop_date columns having null values. So filter those values and instead of `CONVERT` please use `CAST`, because the convert you used cause an error for certain values

Sample:

```
DECLARE @End_date AS VARCHAR(50) = '2016-05-15'; 
SELECT YEAR (CAST(@End_date as DATETIME));
SELECT YEAR (CONVERT(DATETIME, @End_date, 104 ));
```

**Note: I manually type the code by seeing your image. Please correct if any typo.**

So the below code will work for your expectation:

```
SELECT theyear, SUM(isstart) as starts, SUM(isstop) as stops
FROM ( 
     SELECT YEAR(CAST([start_date] AS DATETIME)) as theyear, 1 as isstart, 0 as isstop
     FROM Subscribers 
     WHERE [start_date] IS NOT NULL

     UNION ALL

     SELECT YEAR(CAST(stop_date AS DATETIME)) as theyear, 0 as isstart, 1 as isstop
     FROM Subscribers
     WHERE stop_date IS NOT NULL
)s
GROUP BY theyear
ORDER BY theyear
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help Arulkumar but not working :( . I get the message: Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Can you please share few of your start_date and stop_date values from your table. I want to check in what format the date values are stored

Comment: start_date (varchar,(50),null) { 2001-09-16,1997-01-13,2000-12-08, ... } stop_date (varchar,(50),null) { NULL,2004-12-17,2004-10-23,NULL, ...}

Comment: Hmmm, something fishy. Those are valid format and should satisfy the CAST. Then the issue is with NULL filter i think so. Couls you simply execute the query `SELECT * FROM Subscribers WHERE stop_date IS NOT NULL`,? Check it returning the NULL values also?

Comment: I got this code from a book then it should work but unfortunately it is not. Not sure if I should convert the entire field start_date to datetime and also stop_date to date_time and then use the code. Do you think it is reasonable ?

Comment: if I write SELECT * FROM Subscribers WHERE stop_date IS NOT NULL I get the same { NULL,2004-12-17,2004-10-23,NULL, ...}

Comment: Then that is the issue, NULL filtering fails. Please try `SELECT * FROM Subscribers WHERE stop_date != 'NULL'` and what is the output ?

Comment: You are right now I get only the values { 2004-12-17,2004-10-23, ...}

Comment: So instead of checking `IS NOT NULL` in where clause for start_date and stop_date, check `!= 'NULL'` in both places. It solves your problem?

Comment: Hi Arulkurmar, I made the change != 'NULL' in the code you provided above. Also used the first sample statement. but the result is Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.  I am trying to find the problem

Comment: Does the sample statement (DECLARE @End_date AS VARCHAR(50)...) is relevant to the code ?

Comment: No, those are sample data for your understanding. Those are not required.

Comment: I tried USE Subscribers
SELECT theyear, SUM(isstart) as starts, SUM(isstop) as stops
FROM ( 
     SELECT YEAR(CAST([start_date] AS DATETIME)) as theyear, 1 as isstart, 0 as isstop
     FROM Subscribers 
     WHERE [start_date] IS NOT NULL

     UNION ALL

     SELECT YEAR(CAST(stop_date AS DATETIME)) as theyear, 0 as isstart, 1 as isstop
     FROM Subscribers
     WHERE stop_date != 'NULL'
)s
GROUP BY theyear
ORDER BY theyear but it is not working it says Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. there's a typo ?

Comment: NULL handling for start_date, there also you have NULL values right. Change `WHERE [start_date] IS NOT NULL` to `WHERE [start_date] != 'NULL'`

Comment: You are the man ! It worked as wanted. Thanks a lot ! Have a good night !

Comment: Glad, the issue is solved. Just a note, next time when you post new question instead of the image as code please type your code in question. It may save the time of the person who answering and also avoid the typo errors. :)

Comment: Sure I will follow this rule. Thanks a lot !